# $wpdb->prepare() warning in WordPress 3.5

Tags: database, errors, wpdb

I am receiving this warning when I try to run a database query:

> **Warning:** Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare()

The offending query is:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $metatable
        WHERE meta_key LIKE '%matchme%'
        AND meta_value IS NOT NULL
        AND meta_value <> ''" 
    )
);
```

Is there a way to remove the error by modifying the above query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the call to `$wpdb->prepare()`:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var(
    "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $metatable
    WHERE meta_key LIKE '%matchme%'
    AND meta_value IS NOT NULL
    AND meta_value <> ''"
);
```

In this case, the `$wpdb->prepare()` function is **not doing anything**. There are no variables holding unknown values, therefore there is no need to sanitize them.

If you *did* have variables that need sanitizing, you can add a second argument to the function:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM %s
        WHERE meta_key LIKE '%matchme%'
        AND meta_value IS NOT NULL
        AND meta_value <> ''",
    $metatable )
);
```

**Relevant links:**

- [PHP Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare()](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/)
- [Ticket #22873: Consider moving to a notice for $wpdb->prepare in 3.5.1](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22873)

Comment: The "other possibility" won't work. You can't quote a table name. Prepare should only be used for values.