# wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly

Tags: php, query, wpdb, uninstallation

I have this code to remove orphaned posts after deleting custom post type.

It works, but this code...

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
    "DELETE a,b,c FROM wp_posts a
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON (a.ID=b.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID=c.post_id)
    WHERE a.post_type='attorneys'"
  )
);
```

...is throwing this error:

> PHP Notice:  wpdb::prepare was called **incorrectly**. The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder.

So, after reading [the explanation](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/) on make.wordpress.org by Andrew Nacin, I (sorta) gather that ...well.. I'm missing the second argument.

Then after reading [this stack post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/76076/12116), I'm wondering if I even need the `prepare()` function. **Are there** any variables holding unknown values? I'm not clear on this.

...what am I missing?

UPDATE: This code also works, but w/o the prepare() I wonder if its safe.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( 
  "DELETE a,b,c FROM wp_posts a
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON (a.ID=b.object_id)
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID=c.post_id)
  WHERE a.post_type='attorneys'"
);
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's always advised to use `$wpdb->prepare` when you are taking input from user. This will help in protecting queries against SQL Injection. For more details, check the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)

When you use `$wpdb->prepare`, you must pass the variables to the query. In your case, you can skip using `$wpdb->prepare` as you are using a hard coded value. But if you have the same value in terms of a variable, you need to modify it as below

```
$post_type = 'attorneys';

$wpdb->query( 
     $wpdb->prepare(
          "DELETE a,b,c FROM wp_posts a
          LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON (a.ID=b.object_id)
          LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID=c.post_id)
          WHERE a.post_type=%s",
          $post_type
     )
);
```